S3 data persistence using localstack community edition docker image
I'm working with the localstack/localstack image to mock S3 locally
, and this is what I have for it in my docker compose right now:
localstack-main:
  container_name: localstack-main
  image: localstack/localstack:latest
  ports:
    - "4566:4566"
    - "4510-4559:4510-4559"
  environment:
    - DEBUG=1
    - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - ./localstack-data:/var/lib/localstack
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  networks:
    - mynetwork

The issue here is with the persistence of data in the volume. I'm able to create buckets, put objects, and retrieve them, but if I stop running my container, all that data doesn't persist and I need to recreate the buckets. If I look at my localstack-data directory, even after creating the buckets, I see this:

where all the subdirectories are empty other than cache, which just contains a few pem files and a machine.json file that are generated when I run the container. This is consistent with what I'm seeing in the docker container: no data is being stored in /var/lib/localstack. The only place I'm able to find the buckets and objects I've created in the files of the docker container is in /tmp/localstack-s3-storage. If I modify the volumes in my docker compose to look like this:
volumes:
   - ./localstack-data:/tmp/localstack-s3-storage
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

I am able to see the buckets and objects in my localstack-data directory, but if I restart my container, even though the buckets are still in my local directory, The command
aws --profile local --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 s3api list-buckets

shows I have no buckets created. What's going on here? I've used localstack (with persistent data) in the past without issue. Has something changed that I'm not aware of?

LocalStack Community edition does not support data persistence.

@HarshMishra is this new? I definitely had data persistence on a different project as little as six months ago without setting up a localstack pro account

@HarshMishra Why wouldn't a Docker Container support data persistence? Isn't this a general concept? Usually you just need to mount volumes using paths from the host into the correct locations inside the Container?

@DillonBrock Data persistence for community image was removed around LocalStack v1, and you may be using a very old image.

@user2138149 Unfortunately, these are business decisions. Supporting persistence requires a lot of engineering hours hence we decided to push this to the Pro image.
